# Unable to print the correct result on If function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

please check the if statment. May I know why the result doesnt return on `dt[smaCompare]` variable?

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np


start = dt.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,7,4)

df = web.DataReader('TD', 'yahoo', start, end)

ma = 50

smaString = "Sma_" + str(ma)

df[smaString] = df.iloc[:,5].rolling(window=ma).mean()

smaCompare = "compare"

for i in df.index:
    if (df["Adj Close"][i]>df[smaString][i]):
        df[smaCompare] = "higher"
    else:
        df[smaCompare] = "lower"
        

print(df)
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: Did you mean to do `df[smaCompare][i]` in your loop?

Comment: What's the issue? I just ran this and the df prints fine with a compare column. There doesn't seem to be any "lower" values though in the smaCompare column.

Comment: I can't find any issue in this code as I have run it myself and the result seems perfect>>>>what are you expecting?

Comment: The smaCompare column doesnt has any "lower" result